# specflow: feed data from a file and run scenarios async in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow

Having this `feature`:

```
Feature: ServiceAdd
    Check if addition works well

@someTest
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I connected to the api
    And I check the result
    | a | b | ExpectedResult |
    | 1 | 2 | 3              |
    | 4 | 2 | 6              |
    | -1| 2 | 1              |
    | 1 | 2 | 3              |
    | 1 | 2 | 3              |
    | 1 | 2 | 3              |
```

and the `c#` code:

```
    [Given(@"I check the result")]
    public void GivenICheckTheResult(Table table)
    {
     ......
    }
```

I have some questions:

1. How to run the test for all values in the table `async` (I don't want to wait for the result to start a new test)?
2. How to feed these values from a file or a database so that the values are automatically read by the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use a test runner that support running the tests in parallel. Currently that is NUnit3, XUnit2, SpecRun or NCrunch I believe.
2. You can probably use the [Specflow+ excel extension](http://specflow.org/plus/excel/) for this, though I have not used it so can't be sure it fits this use case, and it is a paid extension.